# Codeigniter : get array value from view and send to contoller and model

Tags: postgresql, codeigniter

view:insert_view.php

```
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
<input type="text" name="val[]" />
}
```

Table:

```
create table val_ex(val character varying);
```

controller:insert_ctl.php

```
$data['val'] =  $this->input->post('val')
```

but it doesn't work it
.And i don't know how to write model to insert data to table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know postgresql I just say How to insert records in model

**Controller :-**

```
$data['val'] =  $this->input->post('val');

foreach($this->input->post('val') as $value) {

$this->model_name->insert_ctl($value);

}
```

**Model :-**

```
public function insert_ctl($value) {

$Array = array ('val' => $value);

$this->db->insert("val_ex", $Array);

}
```